# Why PostgreSQL do not blame `into _res` here?

Tags: postgresql

I have query:

```
SELECT p.*, crate.*
  into _res
FROM LATERAL service_level_tree( 1 ) st -- Get service_level **hierarchy**
LEFT JOIN price p ON                                -- Get Price
        p.service_level_id = st.id                  --  for all levels at hierarchy
    AND p.service_type_id  = 165       --  for given service
    AND p.period_id        = 10             --  for given period
LEFT JOIN currency_rate crate ON                    -- Get currency rate for conversion
        crate.from_currency_id = p.currency_id      --  from currency of price
    AND crate.to_currency_id   = app_currency()     --  to   requested currency
WHERE p.id IS NOT NULL                              -- Let inheritance to work. Ignore levels without prices
ORDER BY st.depth                                   -- Fetch leaf price first
```

But when executing it I get the error:

```
Query execution failed

Reason:
SQL Error [42701]: ERROR: column "id" specified more than once
```

Why PostgreSQL blame "id" here instead of `into _res`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select ... into some_table from ...` is a somewhat deprecated version of `create table some_table as select ...`

When you you create a (new) table, column names in the table must be unique.

The error message tells you that both tables (`price` and `currency_rate`) have a column named `id`. Your SELECT list contains **all** columns from both tables (without renaming them) and thus your result has (at least) two `id` columns.

You will need to rename those columns when you create a new table, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE _res
AS
SELECT p.id as price_id, 
       ... other columns from the price table ...
       crate.id as currency_id, 
       ... other columns ...
FROM LATERAL service_level_tree( 1 ) st -- Get service_level **hierarchy**
LEFT JOIN price p ON                                -- Get Price
        p.service_level_id = st.id                  --  for all levels at hierarchy
    AND p.service_type_id  = 165       --  for given service
    AND p.period_id        = 10             --  for given period
LEFT JOIN currency_rate crate ON                    -- Get currency rate for conversion
        crate.from_currency_id = p.currency_id      --  from currency of price
    AND crate.to_currency_id   = app_currency()     --  to   requested currency
WHERE p.id IS NOT NULL                              -- Let inheritance to work. Ignore levels without prices
ORDER BY st.depth
```

This is another good example why `select *` is usually bad coding style.

Comment: Always have a feeling that DB should have ability to return extended info about columns. About column's parent -- the table. eg. this column from that table. and about its type. This will not force user to write columns definitions for functions that returns `record`. Also in my case the query will just work: ambiguous columns will have full names: `crate.id`, `p.id` and user, if it desire, can set explicit name as usual. This feature will decrease count of such errors and more things will **just work**

Comment: "*ambiguous columns will have full names*" - no they won't. The column name is `id` even if you write `crate.id`

Comment: Yes, It has `crate.id` at this level. But the resulting table *can not have* duplicates, thus it would be handy if DB resolve those by extending name to `crate.id`. Then someone will write `res_table."crate.id"` or `res_table."p.id"` to refer desired column. But all these just my thoughts